# How to enter textual subscripts and superscripts?

Tags: front-end, formatting, writing

When I add a sub- or superscript to a letter in a `"Text"` cell using the "Writing Assistant" palette this letter becomes `Italic`:

[image: screenshot]

Moreover the letter "v" in the subscript is wrongly formatted as being a variable. How to typeset it as `Plain`?

Comment: `SingleLetterItalics -> False`?

Comment: @rm One way is to press Ctrl+Shift+E, find the inline cell and replace `TraditionalForm` style with `"Text"`. Addition of `SingleLetterItalics -> False` itself does not work if the style is `TraditionalForm`. Is it possible to make `"Text"` the default style for inline cell when it is automatically created while editing a `"Text"` cell using a palette?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The palette does not influence anything. You can get the same text cell simply pressing ALT+7. I think your question is: how to make cell style that types "Text" but does not auto-format in `TraditionalForm` when dealing with complex in-line math expressions. That probably deserves a separate post.

Comment: @Vitaliy I have created [separate question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19372/280) as you suggest.

Answer (score 9):

You can compute in a separate cell this expression:

```
Subscript[C, 3 v]
```

and then paste the output in your in-line text where you need it. Many things will work, including ideas from comments, - compare the difference in the outlook:

```
Row@{
  Style[Subscript[C, 3 v], 100], Spacer[30],
  Style[Subscript[C, 3 v], 100, "Text"], Spacer[30],
  Style[Subscript[C, 3 v], 100, SingleLetterItalics -> False], Spacer[30],
  Style[Subscript[C, 3 v], 100, FontFamily -> "Amienne"]}
```

[image]

To understand the difference click in any version and press **CTRL+SHIFT+E**. I guess you need to choose the version more suitable for your case.

While j-- idea is neat and preferable for simple cases, while dealing with complex in-line expressions with many indexes and other italicized forms - it is better compute desirable style at once for the whole expression.

To address programatically  issue mentioned by Jens - the gab between characters in the subscript - one could use

```
Subscript[C, Row[{3 , v}]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Stylistically, the `Italic` toggling, the `Text` or `SingleLetterItalics` solutions all still have one problem: the **spacing** between the `3` and the `v` is too large because it's treated as if it's a multiplication. What I'd consider correct output would be this:

[image: correct]

and **not** this:

[image: bad]

I'm using the version 8 default style, but the argument is the same in version 9.

And how do I get the correct output? Unfortunately, it requires several additional key presses:

- Type `C3v` without `Subscript` in an inline cell
- highlight the `3v` and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>$-$</kbd> twice to shrink the text size appropriate for a subscript (I needed to re-highlight the `3v` while shrinking it)
- with the `3v` still highlighted, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>$\downarrow$</kbd> (on Mac; it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> on PC) four times to shift the baseline to subscript level.

I wish I had an easier answer, but if you want the "right" look this appears to be the shortest path. I tried doing the `Subscript` the normal way and just adjusting the `v` to the left afterwards, but then I can't get it to be in plain text anymore (it stays italic no matter what I do).

It may be best to define such textual subscripts as "macros" if you plan on re-using them.

Answer (score 5):

You could, for example, type the sentence and the subscript part just as you did using the Writing Assistant pallette. Then, you can highlight the letter C and switch it to `Plain` using the command `Italic` (on Windows, Ctrl+I or using the Writing assistants pallette). The same principle works also for the subscript.

Answer (score 5):

You could take the approach of defining a custom style to make the text look however you like, within the bounds of *Mathematica*'s formatting capabilities.  For example, in the private style sheet I paste:

```
Cell[StyleData["NoItalic"],
 StyleMenuListing->None,
 SingleLetterItalics->False,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 AutoSpacing->False,
 ZeroWidthTimes->True
]
```

Now in a new text cell enter my subscript and select it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and enter `NoItalic`, which yields:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see this also addresses the spacing concern that Jens discussed.  You can keep multiple styles for different purposes, each with potentially extensive customization.

Comment: **Addendum**: An Alt + (number) shortcut can be assigned to a style of you use it a lot, making this method very quick indeed.

Answer (score 4):

One satisfactory workaround is to represent as `String` all the text and use the option `ShowStringCharacters -> False`:

```
Style[Subscript["C", "3v"], "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
```

[image: screenshot]

I think that such option should be included in the "Writing Assistant" palette. At this moment there is not too many assistance from it...