# How to make "Text" Cell which does not auto-format in TraditionalForm in-line math expressions?

Tags: front-end, formatting, writing

This is a continuation of the previous post: [How to enter textual subscripts and superscripts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19364/280).

When dealing with complex in-line math expressions inside a `"Text"` cell *Mathematica* by default formats them in `TraditionalForm`. Is it possible to force *Mathematica* to create in-line cells with the same style as the style of enclosing cell?

Comment: Somewhat related question: [Inconsistent display of TraditionalForm in version 9](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16154/245)

Answer (score 3):

```
 Options[EvaluationNotebook[], CommonDefaultFormatTypes]
 (* 
 {CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Input" -> StandardForm, 
 "InputInline" -> StandardForm, "Output" -> StandardForm, 
 "OutputInline" -> StandardForm, "Text" -> TextForm, 
 "TextInline" -> TraditionalForm}}
  *)
```

So changing the setting for `"TextInLine"` to `TextForm` should give what you need:

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"TextInline" -> TextForm}]
```