# Text with subscript is automatically Italic

Tags: graphics, text

I am creating a figure for a document using `Graphics` in which there is `Text` with some variables and again those same variables with some subscripts. The `Text` with subscript is automatically *Italic*. I do not want this, especially because it contrasts with the variables without subscript which are not *Italic*. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: PleasePostAPicture.png

Comment: Does `Text[yourtext,  FormatType -> StandardForm]` give what you need?

Comment: Graphics[{Text["P", {0, 0}], 
  Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(q\)]\)", {1/4, 0}], 
  Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(q\)]\)", {2/4, 0}, 
   FormatType -> StandardForm]}]
Yes, it does. Thank you kguler.

Comment: I recommend `Text[Style[Subscript["P", "q"], 32], {2/4, 0}]`

Comment: Related: [(19364)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19364/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is nice, easy way to do it that will not affect the displayed font,

```
Graphics[Text[Style[Subscript["P", "q"], 36], {1/2, 0}], ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

[image: pq]

#### Update

The OP asks, "Is there an easy way to use this trick within a sentence?"

I ask, what is easy? But here is something using `Row` and not too difficult.

```
Graphics[
  Text[Row[{"The variable ", Subscript["P", "q"], " is positive"}], {0, 0}],
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
  AspectRatio -> 1/6,
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: sentence]

Comment: Interesting how 'Text[Style[Subscript["P", "q"], 36], {1/2, 0}]' and 'Text[Style[Subscript[P, q], 36], {1/2, 0}]' makes a difference.

Comment: It is because in the first case P is a String while in the second case it is a variable.

Comment: Is there an easy way to use this trick within a sentence? As in something like 'Text["The variable"<>Subscript["P", "q"]<>"is positive", {0, 0}]'.

Comment: Well done! Thank you for the quick update.

Answer (score 5):

While I think that [m_goldberg's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57142/280) is the simplest when you type the text by hands, here is the convenient way to disable *italicization* of single letters which will work in all cases:

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style[Subscript[P, q], 36, "SingleLetterItalics" -> False], {1/2, 
   0}], ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `FormatType -> StandardForm` inside `Text`.

Using the example in OP's comment:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], 
          Text[Style["P", 32], {0, 0}], 
          Text[Style[Subscript[P, q], 32], {1/4, 0}], 
          Text[Style[Subscript[P, q], 32], {2/4, 0}, FormatType -> StandardForm]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting how 'Text[Style[Subscript["P", "q"], 36], {1/2, 0}]' and 'Text[Style[Subscript[P, q], 36], {1/2, 0}]' makes a difference.