# Creating subscripts from a list

Tags: output-formatting

I want to use `Subscript`s to prettify a matrix and started the following way

```
Subscript[a, bb] // TraditionalForm
Subscript[a, b,b] // TraditionalForm
Subscript[Subscript[a, b], b] // TraditionalForm
```

The results are
$$
a_{bb}\\
a_{b,b}\\
a_{b_b}
$$
I want to use the first type.

But, I need to create the `Subscript` $a$ with elements from a list, like so

```
list = {b,c,d};
Subscript[a, list[[1]] list[[1]]] // TraditionalForm
Subscript[a, list[[1]], list[[1]]] // TraditionalForm
Subscript[Subscript[a, list[[1]]], list[[1]]] // TraditionalForm
```

Then, the result is
$$
a_{b^2}\\
a_{b,b}\\
a_{b_b}
$$

Sticking with the first type; So, How do I prevent that $b^2$? Or, how do I erase the comma from second output?

Comment: Possibly related: [(17633)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17633/121), [(19364)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19364/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html):

```
Subscript[a, Row@{b, b}]
```

a<sub>bb</sub>

Consider also [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) but beware that it is *not* an inert (formatting) function.

```
Indexed[a, {b, b}]
```

a<sub>bb</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"b", "c", "d"};
Subscript[a, list[[1]] <> list[[1]]] // TraditionalForm
```

or

```
list = {b, c, d};
Subscript[a, ToString[list[[1]]] <> ToString[list[[1]]]] // TraditionalForm
```